# how can it be that this patent will be granted?

Tags: prior-art

In reference to the patent: [WO2014140543A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014140543A1)

How can it be that this patent will be granted if there are:

-US 20100240990 A1 (http://www.google.com/patents/US20100240990?cl=en)

-CA 2692570 A1 (http://www.google.com/patents/CA2692570A1?cl=en